# TensorFlow attribute 'contrib'

Tags: tensorflow, migration

I am trying to compile an old TensorFlow code on the latest version (TensorFlow 2.4.1) on my Mac.  I have employed

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()
```

I am successful in compiling most of the code, however, I am unable to deal with tf.contrib.layers.  I do realize that contrib is taken down on TensorFlow 2.x.  Is there a way to overcome this issue?  Is there a migration procedure for contrib?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it is not available. You might have to convert it to keras.

From the tensoflow documentatin

> A large amount of older TensorFlow 1.x code uses the Slim library, which was packaged with TensorFlow 1.x as tf.contrib.layers. As a contrib module, this is no longer available in TensorFlow 2.x, even in tf.compat.v1. Converting code using Slim to TensorFlow 2.x is more involved than converting repositories that use v1.layers. In fact, it may make sense to convert your Slim code to v1.layers first, then convert to Keras.